# Group by one column and compare text similarity pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sentence-similarity

I have a dataframe with almost 1 million rows and columns as below:

```
  VIN                  Complaints                                  Repairs  Key
 12234          Customer states engine issues                        yes     1
 12234          Car wont start. Engine broke down                    no      2
 12234          Vehicle battery was replaced                         yes     3
 12231          Car shut down, battery problem                       no      4
 12231          Cool and hot air coming from ac                      yes     5
 12231          Issue with temperature moderator, ac replaced        yes     6
 12231          air conditioner not working fine                     no      7
```

I am looking to group the df by 'VIN' and compare the pairwise text similarity of 'Complaints' with the first 'yes' of 'Repairs'.

For instance, 12234 VIN group with the first Repairs as 'Yes' in this example "Customer states engine issues" should be compared against other two complaints of the same VIN group. (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) for 12234 VIN group and (5,4) (5,5) (5,6) (5,7) for 12231 VIN group.

Desired output

```
  VIN                  Complaints                                  Repairs  Key   Text_distance
 12234          Customer states engine issues                        yes     1       1
 12234          Car wont start. Engine broke down                    no      2       1
 12234          Vehicle battery was replaced                         yes     3       0 
 12231          Car shut down, battery problem                       no      4       0
 12231          Cool and hot air coming from ac                      yes     5       1
 12231          Issue with temperature moderator, ac replaced        yes     6       1
 12231          air conditioner not working fine                     no      7       1
```

I tried the below code, but couldn't get the desired result

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
trsfm = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Complaints'])
df['Text_distance']= df.groupby('VIN').apply(lambda x: x.cosine_similarity(trsfm.values, trsfm.values[:, None]))
```

How to get around with it? Also, please suggest in my scenario if Jaccard/ jaro_distance/ cosine/ something else is more efficient.

Comment: _but couldn’t get the desired result_ Can you be more specific? _please suggest in my case if Jaccard/ jaro_distance/cosine/ something else is more efficient._ Efficient in what way?

Comment: That seems like it might be off-topic, see [help/on-topic], [ask].